# Summer has come and I don't know what to do

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

During the summer, most plants wither and stop growing. It's also very dangerous to stay around in the base, because things keep smoldering up and you will probably not have enough ice in store to keep them cool.

While roaming the world, I noticed that mushrooms still appear to be growing, so I can pick them up as crock pot ingredients.

I just checked out the caves and it's still pretty hot in there, in addition to darkness for which I wasn't quite prepared and with all the grass bushes withered, I'm not sure how I can keep a stable supply of light sources.

With so little food and everything just waiting to burn to ashes, it doesn't look like there is going to be much "free" time.

But what else can I do when it's so hot all the time? Where can I find a safe place where the heat can't get me and my valuable items?

Comment: Summer is one of the things that completely ruins the experience of the new DLC for me.  I'm looking forward to someone answering this question because I hate playing with RoG disabled but I can't stand or survive summer.

Comment: For some reason it ended when I dropped down a cave and climbed back up. It suddenly turned into winter. I was like 4 days into summer, so I have no idea why that happened. It was still during the beta, so maybe it was a bug.

Comment: Isn't RoG still in beta?  That is odd.

Comment: @Mkalafut yeah, see the steam store page http://store.steampowered.com/app/282470/

Comment: Upvoted because of the title.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Summer), wilting plants will return to normal in Autumn even without fertilizer that they require to perk up in Summer.

The game really never seems to encourage players to bunker down and wait out seasons, but rather to adapt to the season, and get out there to explore. How about a wearable Ice Cube, Straw Hat, frozen Thermal Stone?

An Ice Flingomatic can protect your structures and things, but smoldering objects can be cooled with Ice, Fertilizer, an Ice Staff, or your hands at the cost of health. The wiki suggests as you did to avoid camp as a last resort, as they will only begin to smolder when the player is nearby.

Comment: I ended up using Thermal Stones and carrying built endothermic campfires to cool down during summer.

Answer (score -2):

just use a summer frest, two thermal stones that you switch in between, and an ice box to cool them down in.